Cookies FPAU and FPGSID
I recently implemented consent mode v2 using Google Tab Manager Server. In principle it works well and respects user preferences regarding cookie consent, but there are 2 cookies that continue to appear regardless of this consent and they are FPAU and FPGSID. Does anyone know what these cookies are for and how to delete them?
I have tried in GTM to disable the Google tag and these cookies disappear, so the problem seems to be related to this tag, but I still don't understand the reason for the error.

Google has an overview over their cookies: https://business.safety.google/adscookies/, which mentions at least FPAU (but not FPGSID).
